# Feeds import from Restful Web Service module output

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a D7 website, which expose a node through the module `Restful Web Service` https://www.drupal.org/project/restws

It does exposed my website node in Json format.  The only issue I have, is the photo field, which has multiple images  but JSON output from RESTWS is only expose the `photo file id`, not the file name.

My question, is there're plugin for the Feeds module that I can use to convert the file ID to a file name, so the feed can import that.  Or is there other way that I can use to directly import the file fid to Drupal.

Here's a little info about my website:  The user can list their content on `bronze plan content type`, and then they decide to upgrade to `silver content type`, what I'm doing in the background, is export the bronze content type through Restful Web Service and re-import through feeds to `silver content type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to post my plan for everyone to review and response.  After days of no response, it does mean I'm having a crazy idea.

I've re-think my solution and came up with writing my own custom module to do the data copy from one content type to another.  It was easy than I expected.  Copy of data from one content type to another is very easy if the both field type are the same.  It's a straight assign of field from one node object to another content type object.  That's it.